# Correlation coefficient of x and y

Tags: correlation, poisson-distribution, expected-value, regression-coefficients, poisson-binomial-distribution

If we have $$ X\sim Poisson(\lambda), Y|X = x\sim Binomial(x+1,p) $$ What is the 
correlation coefficient of  X and Y?

So I used $$\rho=\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(x)Var(Y)}} = \frac{E[X[E[Y|X]]-E[X]E[E[Y|X]]}{\sqrt{E[X](E[E[Y|X]^2] -E[E[Y|X]]^2)}}$$
Is this right? Because I got a wacky answer, and is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder how you come up with your denominator because by [Law of Total Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance):

$$\begin{align}\operatorname{var}(Y)&=\operatorname{var}(E[Y|X])+E[\operatorname{var}(Y|X)]=\operatorname{var}((X+1)p)+E[(X+1)p(1-p)]\\&=p^2\lambda+p(1-p)(\lambda+1)=p(\lambda+1-p)\end{align}$$
and $\operatorname{var}(X)=\lambda$. The numerator seems OK.

Comment: thank you so much!!